# HTTP request modification in Firefox OS

Tags: firefox-os

I'm making an app, it just loads a website. I need to modify the user agent of the http reqeust. I also need to cancel requests made by the site if URI matches a pattern (i.e. "ads").

How can I listen/control all HTTP requests made in my app is there an API for this?

Comment: Update your question with more details instead of opening a new question on the same subject.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just for you you can change the user agent on the phone in the user prefs (user.js file on your phone that you can access through `adb shell`).

Otherwise your best option is to use a reverse proxy.

```
APP -> Reverse proxy -> Real website
```

The reverse proxy is a server application that has full control over the HTTP request and can strip off UA header or replace it with new ones etc.

Third one: Use the [mozTCPSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.mozTCPSocket) API to create HTTP requests to the server. If you only do GET it should not be that hard and you have full control over the request. If you only ever talk to one server it could be OK, but it'll be more work.

Comment: I want to make an app out of this. I'm an addon dev and am used to hacking up http reuqests with `observer`s on `http-on-modify-request`, is there nothing like this for ff-os? I would like to not use proxy as i would have to make my own server? I would like to not make requests, i just want pages to load in an iframe and i modify those http requsts like i do on desktop with xpcom.

Comment: Nope, at the moment it's not possible to modify the http headers in an iframe.

Comment: Hey @Jan I'm still trying to make this app without the adb shell trick. I got the iframe and its loading whatsmyuseragent.com can you please help me with example for reverse proxy.

Comment: Is there anyway to set the user agent user pref when user focuses my app and then reset it when they unfocus my app? Im still stuck on this one :(