# APP -> Reverse proxy -> Real website

Tags: firefox-os

Hi all I'm trying to implement a simple app which has an iframe and pages that load in that iframe i want to customize the user agaent. It was recommended to me that one option was "reverse proxy" https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219796/1828637

Can you please show me a working example I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP Request Modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153906/http-request-modification)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spoof useragent of pages loaded in my iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499239/spoof-useragent-of-pages-loaded-in-my-iframe)

Comment: Hey @Cod1ngFree i still havent figured out any of them. Do you know how to do this by chance?

Comment: I am not sure If you can use navigator.userAgent. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Cod1ngFree it seems that resets every time the page changes :( I need it to be set before page loads so the site within loads thinking its different

Comment: I am not sure how are you loading those pages, I bet that the Mozbrowser API would help you a lot.

One way to do it is to change the useragent for each webpage (why not?), but you could ask @bfrancis for a better approach, he is who developed the Mozbrowser API.

Comment: Thanks @Cod1ngFree I'll chat with him! :)